# General solution of $f(x) + xf'(x) + 2x^2f''(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Wondering if I get this right. Assuming $f(x) = x^\alpha$ is a solution, you must have $1 + \alpha +2\alpha(\alpha-1) = 0$, thus 
$$\alpha =\frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{7}}{4} .$$

This results in

$$f(x) = \sqrt[4]{x}\cdot\cos\Big(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}\log x\Big).$$

Not sure if this is correct, also, how do you find the general solution? I am missing that part.

Comment: If $x^{\alpha_1}$ and $x^{\alpha_2}$ are solutions then so is $C_1x^{\alpha_1}+C_2x^{\alpha_2}$ for any constants $C_1,C_2\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you, I made the correction.

Comment: To check if it is correct, plug $f$ in the equation (it works).

Comment: Euler equation！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, set $x=e^t$, which gives

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac1x\frac{df}{dt}$$ and $$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=-\frac1{x^2}\frac{df}{dt}+\frac1{x^2}\frac{d^2f}{dt^2}.$$

Then

$$2\ddot f-\dot f+f=0$$ has the general solution

$$f(t)=c_+e^{t(1+i\sqrt7)/4}+c_-e^{t(1-i\sqrt7)/4}=e^{t/4}\left(c_c\cos\dfrac{\sqrt7t}4+c_s\sin\dfrac{\sqrt7t}4\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

While you identified $$Re(e^{α\ln x})=\frac12(e^{α\ln x}+e^{\bar α\ln x})$$ as a solution, one finds that also $$Im(e^{α\ln x})=\frac1{2i}(e^{α\ln x}-e^{\bar α\ln x})$$ is a real-valued linear combination of the exponential basis solutions.

Or as was said in the comments, with the cosine solution you also get a sine solution.